# limiting input to only y/n using loop

Tags: c++, loops

I'm new to programming and I need help with this homework of mine. I tried to search for the issue but because I'm completely new to programming I didn't know what I should be searching for.

My question is, if the user does not input 'y' or 'n', I want the program to ask them the same question again so that the program will only continue if the user inputs a 'y' or 'n'

the code i wrote below puts me in a loop and it will keeps asking me "Enter another value (y/n)?:" regardless of my response.

```
do{
    cout << "Please enter a numerical value: ";
    cin >> value[n];
    n++;    
    do{
        cout << "Enter another value (y/n)?: ";
        cin >> ans;
    } while (answer != 'y' || answer != 'n');
} while (answer == 'y');
```

Comment: `(answer != 'y' || answer != 'n')` is always true. It would have to be equal to both `y` and `n` at the same time to break out of the loop.

Comment: **PLEASE** don't answer this question with code or direct solution.

Answer (score 3):

Truth table time:

```
answer  |  not y  |  not n  |  not y OR not n
---------------------------------------------------
  y     |  false  |  true   |      true
  n     |  true   |  false  |      true
  x     |  true   |  true   |      true
```

As you can see, there's no way to make your condition `false`. You're expecting to be `false` when the input is either `y` or `n`, but that's not what's happening. How can you fix this? How could you make it `true` only in the last row?

Comment: would answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'

Comment: @Pilly Nope, because then `x` would give `false` too.